# How to develop a system tray application that do some background process in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services, notifications, system-tray

I have developed a notification application with C# winform. 
But now in this i want to add functionality to display a notification window in each 10 seconds.

**My whole application idea is :**

> I want to develop an application that can reside in background. A
>   system try icon display always. When user click on this icon a context
>   menu will open and there would be some options. When user click on a
>   menu a WinForm will appear there. When first time this application
>   will run, a configuration form will show. Also, it will display a
>   notification window in each 10 seconds. This notification window is a
>   small window, it will appear at right bottom of the screen. Just like
>   we see quick heal antivirus notifications.  This application or
>   service should automatic start when computer starts.

Currently i am using this approach :

```
using (ProcessIcon ProccIcon = new ProcessIcon()) // ProcessIcon class encapsulating whole functionlity of system tray icon
{ 
    ProccIcon.Display(); // This will display process icon

    // Make sure the application runs!
    Application.Run(); // application start, when user click on tray icon, menu will display and application execution stuck here until application will not terminate.
}
```

So, **the question is**, What is the best practice to develop this type of application.
**It should be winform application ? or windows service** with with GUI support ? Or any other.
If it should be in WinForm, then what should i do for these two things.

1. Automatic start application when computer start.
2. Should be regularly running in background and display alert in fixed time interval.

Answer (score 0):

I think It should be Window Service.

MY thumb Rule is this:

> If it needs to always run, it should be a service.

**Edit for (To start App whenever system Start):**

you can copy a exe in startup folder. Whenever the computer will start, The Exe will also be start automatically.

OR

Add Registry to start Application

```
 private void RegisterInStartup()
{
    RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
            ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

     registryKey.SetValue("ApplicationName", Application.ExecutablePath);

}
```

For second point you can use the [BackGroundWorker](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners)

**Important Link:**

[How to create Window Service Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[BackgraundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker)

Comment: Can you provide more details on last 2 points of the question ? It would be more helpful for me.

Comment: Is there any other way to start application automatically? And backgound worker works well on a winform, but here, i dont have any active winform, what should i do in this case ?

Comment: I am thinking to develop windows service. Is this a good option, or should i have to go on winforms

Comment: See the registry setting....and I also think that Window Service would be a good option..

Comment: Can you provide detailed description for this in your answer. So that i could be more specific to question and hit only the right answer. That i can accept and it can guide other programmers also.

Comment: Actually your question is not related to specific problem...So I can only provide you links. Go to these link and see how the things work.

Comment: Okk, @vikky thanx for your efforts

Comment: should services have UI interaction though?  Note that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx suggests interactive services are no longer possible.